# Setting all the elements to a same value in C

Tags: c, arrays

Note: There are posts similar to this for C++ only, I didn't find any useful post in regards to C.

I want to set the array of elements with the same value. Of course, this can be achieved simply using a for loop.

But, that consumes a lot of time. Because, in my algorithm this setting array with same value takes place many number of times. Is there any simple way to achieve this in C.

Comment: What is the array type and what is the value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize an array in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by other users, use `memset` if you want to initiate your array with 0 values, but don't do it if the values are not that simple.

For more complicated values, you can have a constant copy of your initial values and copy them later with `memcpy`:

```c
float original_values[100]; // don't modify these values
original_values[0] = 1.2f;
original_values[1] = 10.9f; 
...

float working_values[100]; // work with these values
memcpy(working_values, original_values, 100 * sizeof(float));
// do your task
working_values[0] *= working_values[1];
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a for loop. Any decent compiler will optimize this as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

It is a near certainty that you wouldn't be able to improve substantially on the speed of your `for` loop. There is no magic way to set a value into multiple memory locations faster than it takes to store that value into these multiple memory locations. Regardless of whether you use the `for` loop or not, all the locations must be written to, which takes most of the time.

There is of course the [`void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) for values composed of identical bytes<sup>1</sup>, but under the hood it has a loop. Perhaps the implementation could be very smart about using that loop, but so can the optimizing compiler.

<sup>1</sup> Although `memset` takes an `int`, it converts it to `unsigned char` before setting it into the memory region.

Comment: Here, the value to set is obtained dynamically and is large enough. So, `memset` can be ruled out since it can be used for setting all elements to `unsigned char` only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `memset()` . It fills no of bytes you want to fill with same byte value.[Here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset)
you can read man page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `memset()` function

Example:

```
memset(<array-name>,<initialization-value>,<len>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily `memset` an array to 0.

If you want a different value, it all depends on the type used.

For **char*** arrays you can `memset` them to any value, since char is *almost* always one byte long.

For an **array of structures**, if all fields of a structure are to be initialized with 0 or NULL, you can `memset` it with 0.

You can not memset an array or array of structures to any value other than 0, because memset operates on single bytes. So if you memset an `int[]` with 1, you will not have an array of 1's.

To initialize an array of structures with a custom value, just fill one structure with the desired data and do an assignment it in a `for`. The compiler should do it relatively efficiently for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about initialization see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c). If you want to set the values at a later time then use [memset](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can only set your values to zero for a particular array. Here is an example

```
int arr[5]={0};
```